# How to remove the space after the amsthm caption and the dot?

Tags: amsthm

I've create an unnumbered `amsthm` environment `problem`, and a numbered `amsthm` environment `example`. Then I want to make the numbered `example` environment be unnumbered, so I typed `\let\theexample=\relax` (Why? Because I'm using a template that was already assigned the numbered `example` environment, and I just don't want to change the `.cls` file). Then I found that there's a space between the caption of the environment and the dot. So, how can I remove it?

[image: The space between the caption and the dot.]

The MWE is

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,lipsum}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{problem}{Problem}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}

\begin{document}

\begin{problem}
    \lipsum[6]
\end{problem}

\begin{example}
    \lipsum[6]
\end{example}

\let\theexample=\relax
\begin{example}
    \lipsum[6]
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can define a different environment, so you can also number other examples.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,lipsum}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{problem}{Problem}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\newtheorem*{example*}{Example}

\begin{document}

\begin{problem}
    \lipsum[6]
\end{problem}

\begin{example}
    \lipsum[6]
\end{example}

\begin{example*}
    \lipsum[6]
\end{example*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Instead of messing with the example counter, you could use

```
\let\example\relax
\newtheorem*{example}{Example}
```

in your document to redefine the example environment as unnumbered theorem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,lipsum}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{problem}{Problem}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}

\let\example\relax
\newtheorem*{example}{Example}

\begin{document}

\begin{problem}
    \lipsum[6]
\end{problem}

\begin{example}
    \lipsum[6]
\end{example}

\end{document}
```